# Transaction Rollback in Controller if exception occurred in any service

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I am newbie to spring and I face problem in Transaction.

I have created two Model as below:

```
UserDto - Stored user information
RoleDto - Stored user's role information
```

Service respected to both models are as below (both are annotated with @Transactional):

```
UserService - void saveUser(UserDto userDto) throws Exception;
RoleService - void saveRole(RoleDto roleDto) throws Exception;
```

now when user create account in the application at that time I called "add" method of the controller, which has the code snippet as below:

```
userService.saveUser(userDto);
roleService.saveRole(roleDto);
```

now in this code if exception occurred in Roleservice than it still insert user data into database table. but I want to rollback that too if roleService throws any exception. I tried to find the solution but could not get any good tutorial. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're calling the method makes each of it has its own transaction. Your code can be understood like this:

```
Transaction t1 = Spring.createTransaction();
t1.begin();
try {
    //your first service method marked as @Transactional
    userService.saveUser(userDto);
    t1.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t1.rollback();
} finally {
    t1.close();
}
Transaction t2 = Spring.createTransaction();
t2.begin();
try {
    //your second service method marked as @Transactional
    roleService.saveRole(roleDto);
    t2.commit();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t2.rollback();
} finally {
    t2.close();
}
```

An option to solve this would be to create another service class where its implementation has `RoleService` and `UserService` injected, is marked as `@Transactional` and calls these two methods. In this way, both methods will share the same transaction used in this class:

```
public interface UserRoleService {
    void saveUser(UserDto userDto, RoleDto roleDto);
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserRoleServiceImpl implements UserRoleService {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserDto userDto, RoleDto roleDto) {
        userService.saveUser(userDto);
        roleService.saveRole(roleDto);
    }
}
```

A better design would be to make `RoleDto` a field of `USerDto` and that implementation of `USerService` has a `RoleService` field injected and perform the necessary calls to save each. Note that service classes must provide methods that contains business logic, this also means business logic **rules**. Service classes are not just wrappers for Dao classes.

This could be an implementation of the above explanation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    public void saveUSer(UserDto userDto) {
        //code to save your userDto...
        roleService.saveRole(userDto.getRoleDto());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, i will follow it to solve my problem.many thanks